# Linking to a specific spot on a page in Google Sites

Tags: links, google-classic-sites

I am looking to link a button to a specific line on a page.

Is this possible using Google Sites?

Answer (score 1):

You can use html anchors in Google Sites, even if by default there exists only for table of content :
Open your page in edit mode, toggle the "HTML source view" and add an anchor like this :

```
A <a name="serious">serious</a> crime is one which is associated with imprisonment.
```

You can link your page with the link https://sites.google.com/yoururl/page#serious

You can use this link in the same page (uncheck "Open in a new window"),but if you move your page and the page url change, the link will become invalid.